# Split List elements into Sublists of words for each element in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[split list elements into sub-elements in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51058614/split-list-elements-into-sub-elements-in-pandas-dataframe) this one is super close - but rather than split all elements and put into one list, I need to put them into a sublist.

df:

```
col1
['this is list 1', 'this is list 2', 'this is another list 3']
['this is list 1', 'this is list 2', 'this is another list 3']
['this is list 1', 'this is list 2', 'this is another list 3']
```

I am trying to make the dataframe column look like this:

```
col1
[['this', 'is', 'list', '1'], ['this', 'is', 'list', '2'], ['this', 'is', 'another', lis't', '3']]
[['this', 'is', 'list', '1'], ['this', 'is', 'list', '2'], ['this', 'is', 'another', lis't', '3']]
[['this', 'is', 'list', '1'], ['this', 'is', 'list', '2'], ['this', 'is', 'another', lis't', '3']]
```

Basically split the elements in the list into sublists where each word is the elements/items in the sublist, all within a pandas df column

Comment: My initial thought here is to just do an apply `lambda l: [s.split() for s in l]`

Comment: @ifly6 ooooo fire. done son. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

this did it. Thanks @ifly6

`df['col1'] = df. col1.apply(lambda l: [s.split() for s in l])`

Answer (score 1):

An `apply` solution would be

```
s.apply(lambda l: [s.split() for s in l])
```

I would leave it to someone else to think of a vectorised solution.